# Haskell - No instance for (Eq (Int -> Int)) arising from a use of ‘==’

Tags: haskell, instance, equals, comparable

im currently looking into haskell. I know that i have to make datatypes an instance of Eq in order to compare them.
But Int should already be comparable right ? So i dnt know how to handle the following Error:

> • No instance for (Eq (Int -> Int)) arising from a use of ‘==’
>           (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)

My Code is as follows:

```
myRandomList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]


myFilterList :: [Int] -> [Int]
myFilterList [] = []
myFilterList (x:xs)
        | mod x == 0 = x : myFilterList xs
        | otherwise = myFilterList xs


myDotFunc = map (+ 1) . myFilterList . myRandomList
```

Ps: Im not even sure, if my code would work without this error, please remember that i just started haskell :)

Comment: Well `mod x` is not a number, you need to provide an extra argument.

Comment: Doesn't it say more about location?

Comment: Moreover `myRandomList` is not a function, `myDotFunc` should probably be `myDotFunc = map (+1) . myFilterList` instead.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? It's not a bad question.

Answer (score 2):

You've only given `mod` one argument, in this line:

```
        | mod x == 0 = x : myFilterList xs
--        ^^^^^ HERE
```

So it looks like you're trying to compare functions. You might notice that GHC tells you this in the error:

> No instance for (Eq (Int -> Int)) arising from a use of ‘==’ **(maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)**

I should be `mod x y`, where `y` is the modulo (the 'divider'). I don't know what you want `y` to be, though, So I can't correct your code.

Comment: oh damn :( you are right! i am also new to stackoverflow, should i just delete my question? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NikBerlin No, don't delete it after it has been answered. That would prevent the answerer to gain any reputation. Indeed, SO doesn't even let you delete it when there's an upvoted answer, I believe. (When no answer is posted, deleting is fine if you realize the question is of no value to you and/or to others.)